# crackme crashes when hitting breakpoint

Tags: reverse-engineering, cracking

So I'm trying to improve my skills in reverse engineering, I'm still somewhat of a newbie.
Anyway, I found a crackme that's packed and has several anti debugging checks. (In windows)

If I attach my debugger to the process (After it unpacked), when I put a breakpoint in interesting places, the exe seems to crash if I hit that breakpoint. I'm almost certain that the program doesn't actually check for breakpoints, because even when I overwrote the return instruction to NOPS so that the code execution will hit the INT 3 instruction that are already (conveniently)  there, it still crashes. Well maybe it does check, but even so, it doesn't seems to be the real problem.

It's worth noting that it's not in every place that the program crashes. (just in interesting places that I actually need to debug).

I would appreciate a guideline how should I go about dealing with it. 
Thanks/